# PrimeFaces p:idleMonitor rendered="false" not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a project with `Primefaces 5.1`.

In my project, I used `p:idleMonitor`, on my Start button click the `p:idleMonitor rendered="true"` is working .

On my Stop button click the `p:idleMonitor rendered="false"` not working and the `p:idleMonitor` is still processing.

**Sample Code:**

**index.xhtml**

```
 <p:panel id="mainPanelId">

     <p:commandButton value="Start" update="mainPanelId" action="{Sample.start}"/>

     <p:commandButton value="Stop" update="mainPanelId" action="#{Sample.stop}"/>

     <p:idleMonitor timeout="5000" rendered="#{Sample.idleRendered}">
          <p:ajax event="idle"  oncomplete="PF('dialogId').show();"/>
          <p:ajax event="active" oncomplete="PF('dialogId').hide();"/>
     </p:idleMonitor>

     <p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="dialogId" header="Idle">     
         <p:outputLabel value="Idle Mode Actived!"/>
     </p:dialog>

 </p:panel>
```

**Sample.java**

```
class Sample
{
   private boolean idleRendered;

   public String start()
    {
        idleRendered = true;
        return null;
    }

   public String stop()
    {
       idleRendered = false;
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried PF 6.0 or even 6.1RC2? and another workaround is to use a widgetVar on the idleMonitor and call the 'pause()' function on it

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should do differently.

1. Use `<h:form>`
2. Use actionListener by `p:commandButton` and void methods of your bean

**XHTML**

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="mainPanelId">
        <p:commandButton value="Start" update="mainPanelId"
            actionListener="#{Sample.start}" />

        <p:commandButton value="Stop" update="mainPanelId"
            actionListener="#{Sample.stop}" />

        <h:outputText value="#{Sample.idleRendered}" />
        <p:idleMonitor timeout="5000" rendered="#{Sample.idleRendered}">
            <p:ajax event="idle" oncomplete="PF('dialogId').show();" />
            <p:ajax event="active" oncomplete="PF('dialogId').hide();" />
        </p:idleMonitor>

        <p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="dialogId" header="Idle">
            <p:outputLabel value="Idle Mode Actived!" />
        </p:dialog>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

**Bean**

```
@Named("Sample")
@SessionScoped
public class Sample implements Serializable {

    private boolean idleRendered = true;

    public void start() {
        idleRendered = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        idleRendered = false;
    }

    public boolean isIdleRendered() {
        return idleRendered;
    }

    public void setIdleRendered(boolean idleRendered) {
        this.idleRendered = idleRendered;
    }

}
```

**Update:**
Looks like a bug, here is a workaround:

```
<p:outputPanel rendered="#{Sample.idleRendered}">
    <p:idleMonitor timeout="5000">
        <p:ajax event="idle" oncomplete="PF('dialogId').show();" />
        <p:ajax event="active" oncomplete="PF('dialogId').hide();" />
    </p:idleMonitor>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I used h:form and actionListener in p:commandButton also but still not solved that problem.

Comment: The  <h:outputText value="#{Sample.idleRendered}" /> changes?

Comment: yes, the <h:outputText value="#{Sample.idleRendered}" /> is changed dynamically when clicking on start and stop button, but the idleMonitor component is not stopped when clicked on stop button.

Comment: You can create an issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues or debug the render and post a pull request.

Comment: Tried PF 6.0 or even 6.1RC2? and another workaround is to use a widgetVar on the idleMonitor and call the 'pause()' function on it